# Number of injective up-down functions from $[k] \to [n]$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A function $f : [k] \to [n]$ is called an up-down function if it is injective, strictly increasing from $1$ to $j$ for some $j$ and strictly decreasing from $j$ to $k$.

To find the number of up-down functions for fixed $k$ and $n$.

---

Few things I have observed:

(1) $f(j)$ has the highest value. Hence $f(j) \ge k$.

(2) So the values of $f(x)$ where $x \neq j$ will be between $1$ and $f(j)-1$.

(3) We partition the set  $[f(j)-1]$ into two sets, one of size $j-1$ and another of size $k-j$ and then we have to arrange.

---

Can someone help further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are *disjoint* subsets of $[n]$ such that $|S_1|+|S_2|=k$,

then to the ordered pair $(S_1,S_2)$ you can associate the up-down function $f:[k]\to[n]$ which is uniquely determined by $S_1$ and $S_2$ in the following way:

$f(x)\in S_1$ whenever $1\leq x\leq |S_1|$, and $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $S_1$;

$f(x)\in S_2$ whenever $|S_1|+1\leq x\leq k$, and $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $S_2$.

This is an up-down function, no matter whether $f(|S_1|)>f(|S_1|+1)$ or whether $f(|S_1|)<f(|S_1|+1)$.

**Exercise: any up-down function  is associated to exactly two such ordered pairs, not more than two or fewer than two.**

Choose $T\subset[n]$ such that $T$ has size $k$. Then, choose $U\subset T$ such that $U\neq T$. We can regard $U$ as the first entry in the ordered pair, for which the second pair is already determined to be $T\setminus U$.

The number of ways to do this is $\displaystyle{n\choose k}\times2^k$.

The answer to the question is $\displaystyle{n\choose k}\times2^{k-1}$.

Comment: but we can also have $k=2$ right? Then every injective function is also up-down

Comment: The number of injective function when $k=2$ is $n(n-1)=\binom n2\cdot 2^1,$ so the formula works there. @User8976

Comment: One way to avoid the double-counting is to pick $k$ elements, but partition the $k-1$ smallest elements into $S_1,S_2.$ Basically, the maximum element partitions the set of other elements in the set by those which come before and those which come after.

Comment: Yes, this thing I have observed and written in the question.